# UITableView titleForHeaderInSection is not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I add a tableview to a view controller then try to change its section header titles in IOS 6.0.

I will be changing header strings every-time a specific function is called so I dont want to deal with `(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

I tried to use  `(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` but when I put a breakpoint I see that its not being called.

in.h file I add UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource

in.m

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   //tableview init
    self.meetingList=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, self.ckCal.frame.origin.y + self.ckCal.bounds.size.height+20, 384, 450) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.meetingList setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    self.meetingList.delegate=self;

    //populate mutablearray for tableview here
    [self eventsInThisMonth:[NSDate date]];

    [self.view addSubview:self.meetingList];
}
-(void)eventsInThisMonth:(NSDate *)date
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter  setDateFormat:@"MMMM , yyyy"];
    //self.firstSectionHeader=nil;
    self.firstSectionHeader= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Events in %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
    NSLog(@" self.firstSectionHeader %@ ",self.firstSectionHeader);

}
#pragma Tableview
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.eventHeaders count] + 1;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 35;
}
//set header section labels
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 35)] ;
    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:106/256.0 green:106/256.0 blue:106/256.0 alpha:1.0]];
    UILabel *subjectLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(92, 10, tableView.bounds.size.width, 20)];
    subjectLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    subjectLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gill Sans" size:20];
    subjectLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    subjectLabel.text=self.firstSectionHeader;
    NSLog(@"subjectLabel.text %@",subjectLabel.text);

    if (section==0) {

        //[headerView addSubview:subjectLabel];
        return headerView;
    }
    else
        return nil;


}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section==0) {
         NSLog(@"self.firstSectionHeader in titleForHeaderInSection %@",self.firstSectionHeader);
        return self.firstSectionHeader;
    }
    else
        return nil;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looking at your code... Why would you want to use both, viewForHeaderInSection and titleForHeaderInSection? You are setting the title in viewForHeaderInSection anyway...

Answer (score 18):

I think that's probably because you are only supposed to use one of the two: `viewForHeaderInSection` or `titleForHeaderInSection`.

Comment: What if I want to change the backgroundcolor of the header section.

Comment: You'll just have to make a new header in viewForHeaderInSection.

Comment: You can implement both.  In viewForHeaderInSection I assume you have a UILabel (which holds whatever NSString you're using for the title).  Just set that string by calling titleForHeaderInSection:
Best of both worlds.

Comment: Sure, you can implement both. But if you have viewForHeaderInSection, titleForHeaderInSection will not be called.

Comment: Completely false. They will both be called, in a known order, and in fact this is a perfectly reasonable thing to do - e.g. give it a title string in `titleFor` and then tweak its appearance in `viewFor`.

Comment: You can call `titleForHeaderInSection` from `viewForHeaderInSection` yourself, obviously, but the table view wont call it automatically.

Comment: matt what is the 'known order' and what do you return from the first  to cause the fall through to the second?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `self.meetingList.datasource = self;`

Remember that your viewController has to implemente the UITableViewDelegate and the UITableViewDataSource.

```
YourClass : UITableView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Comment: Your answer is half correct thanks, I tried to upvote your answer but I cant upvote without enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Re: What am I doing wrong.

I am not certain if you are setting datasource and delegate on your view controller in Interface Builder or not. But I believe there is a logic error that impacts the expected outcome.

titleForHeaderInSection:
Asks the data source for the title of the header of the specified section of the table view.

meanwhile

tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
Asks the delegate for a view object to display in the header of the specified section of the table view.

The latter method is overriding behavior defined for the titleForHeaderInSection. Think of it this way; you have one header space that can hold a title OR a custom view that you create to replace the default (title). You are telling the compiler to use a custom view by implementing the second method. To fix this comment out or remove the tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: method or change your logic so that you update the title in your custom view that you pass into the method. At that point titleForHeaderInSection should be hit correctly.

Please consider accepting this answer if it is successful in resolving your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a little old, but make sure you also have:

`-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{`

The tableview will need to know the height before it can grab the view.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you need to NOT implement both

```
(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

If you will implement one at least first method, then

```
- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

won't be called.

Comment: You can implement heightForHeaderInSection, just make sure the height is sufficient. viewForHeaderInSection on the other hand signifies that you want to replace the default style header with your own custom view.

Answer (score 0):

`heightForHeaderInSection` and `titleForHeaderInSection` are both required it would seem. Implementing just `titleForHeaderInSection` didn't work for me, and adding `heightForHeaderInSection` fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do

```
self.meetingList.dataSource=self;
```

in viewDidAppear.